# Xbox 360 Slim red dot when turned on while connected to HDMI and green dot when HDMI is not connected. Both cases - No signal

Tags: xbox-360

When I turned on my Xbox it had the red dot instead of the green dot. All lights on my controller were on and the TV had no signal.

I thought this might be an issue with my power outlet so I connected it to a different one, this time without the HDMI cable. This time the dot remained green but the controller still had all 4 lights on.

I have the 4GB Slim Model

Help me out?

Comment: Do you have any other input cables connected? (AV? VGA?)

Answer (score 1):

This could be a Graphic card mafunction, i suggest attempting to try different cables, but also other cables like AV or VGA.

make sure you only have ONE TYPE of video connected, (i.e., do not have HDMI and AV connected at the same time).

If the problem still persists, and even trying a different TV doesnt work, one option is a [Factory Reset](http://forums.xbox.com/xbox_forums/xbox_support/f/7/t/330913.aspx), keep in mind that it earases the complete harddrive!

An other option would be to contact the MS/XBox helpdesk in your country, or if there is still a warranty/store warranty on there, a visit to the shop you bought it at doesnt seem like a bad idea

Answer (score -1):

The same thing happens to me. Took it apart, disconnected everything and then put it back together and then it works, but when I plug my hdmi in, it turns red. Also I tried the old av and still happens.